# is there a predefined functor for conditional operator in c++?

Tags: c++, conditional-operator, functor

Predefined functors are used as wrappers for operators in c++ to use, for example, in STL algorithms. There seems to be a wrapper for all operators except conditional. Is it missing? If yes, why?

Below is the potential usage for such functor with `std::transform` algorithm

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>

int main() {
   std::vector<int> v1(10), v2(10), v3(10);

   srand(static_cast<unsigned>(time(nullptr)));

   // generates random values in two vectors
   generate(v1.begin(), v1.end(), []{return rand()%100;});
   generate(v2.begin(), v2.end(), []{return rand()%100;});

   // selects the larger element out of corresponding two
   transform(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v3.begin(),
             [](int i, int j){ if (i>j) return i; else return j;});

   // equivalent code with potential conditional functor
   // transform(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v3.begin(),
   //           conditional<>(greater<>)());

   // prints the selected values
   for(auto e: v3) std::cout << e << ", "; std::cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: `if` is a statement, not an operator.

Comment: It's not really possible, because the conditions can be too complex. Not to mention that where would the arguments come from? How would their names be expressed?

Comment: see example commented out code

Comment: Remember that variables must be *declared* before they are used. In your "example" there's no declaration of `i` or `j`. C++ just doesn't work that way.

Comment: With that said, it might be possible using template parameter packs, so you have `conditional<int, int, std::greater<int, int>>()` or something similar. But does it really make things better than `[](auto i, auto j) { return i > j ? i : j; }`? Especially if you want anything more complex, like for example with logical `&&` or `||`?

Comment: edited code a bit

Comment: arguing whether lambdas are better than predefined functors is not the point.

Comment: so, too complicated a concept to be useful, eh?

Comment: The conditional operator is the only one that takes three arguments. Current overloads for `std::transform` take at most two input ranges, so you'd need to first extend it to take three as well. And what would the first range of value type `bool` come from? You could allocate a separate vector just to store the result of `std::greater` and pass that to a ternary-aware `std::transform` along with the same ranges, but that's an incredibly roundabout and inefficient workflow for something that `std::transform` expresses with just one line and a simple, readable lambda expression

Comment: two input ranges, get values, compare, output into output range, see example

Comment: @Mikhail your example is effectively a binary operation. A proper ternary functor would be more general and accept a boolean condition that doesn't always come from the other two arguments.

Comment: Thinking about it, it's not really possible. Like mentioned by @alter_igel you need three inputs for the conditional operator: The condition; The value to return if the condition is true; And the value to return if the condition is false. To set up the condition is relatively easy using template parameter packs, but what about the values to return? How would the `conditional<>` structure know what to return?  In this case you want to return one of two integer values, but you might as well want to return something completely different.

Comment: Not to mention that the condition could be based on completely different values. In short, rather than make an half-assed attempt that wouldn't work for more than a handful of cases, it's better to not try at all, and just use lambdas or other callable objects. But you're welcome to create your own solution for your specific use-case. Just don't expect it to come with the standard library anytime soon, if ever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There seems to be a wrapper for all operators except conditional. Is it missing?

Yes, it is missing. No, it is not the only one missing. There are also no wrappers for the (pre-/post-)increment, (pre-/post-)decrement, subscript, indirection, member access, and comma operators. Also the address of operator, unless you count `std::addressof` (which is not affected by `operator&`).

> If yes, why?

One reason is that it is not an arithmetic or a logical operator. According to cppreference.com, the operator function objects are for "[common arithmetic and logical operations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional#Operator_function_objects)" (plus the function call operator, which is mentioned earlier on the linked page).

Another reason is that the link to standard algorithms is weak. The arithmetic operators directly transform their parameters. The logical operators directly compare their parameters. In contrast, your example of using the comparison operator is indirect, in that the parameters have to go through something else (`std::greater`) in addition to being used as operands. The more you deviate from a direct wrapper, the more likely that your implementation will be weak/wanting.

Stepping away from your specific example, it becomes less clear why this setup should be considered equivalent to "the comparison operator". In general, the first operand (the boolean condition) does not have to depend on the other two operands, so your proposed approach is more of a specialization of the comparison operator than a wrapper for it. Plus, such a specialization would have limited usefulness since it could not transform the parameters, only select one of them. Wrapping the operator in a lambda is much more flexible and powerful. There is not a lot of benefit here for the cost of defining and implementing this specialized wrapper.